# Adding controls to Outlook 2013 "inline response" contextual ribbon

Tags: outlook-addin, ribbon, outlook-2013

I have an Outlook add-in that has been used for the last couple of years. When creating a new email, I had added a group of controls to the ribbon that would appear on the inspector window.

With the advent of Outlook 2013 and the *in-line response* feature, these controls do not appear on the ribbon. There is a new message contextual tab that shows when the in-line response is activated, and ideally this is where I would have the controls show.

The `RibbonType` used for the existing controls is `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose`, but I cannot see any option for the contextual in-line response.

The only solutions I have found on the Internet use Add-in Express but I'm just using VSTO.

Does anybody know how I can get my controls to show on the contextual ribbon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with the Ribbon xml, not with the designer !

```xml
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <contextualTabs>
            <tabSet idMso="TabComposeTools">
                <tab idMso="TabMessage">

                ##Place your content here##

                </tab>
            </tabSet>
        </contextualTabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```